# Restore Things to iPhone from iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, applications, backup, restore

I ended AT&T service with my iPhone, but would still like for it to be useful. When the service was ended, Things was in the process of being updated, and I deleted it from my iPhone (not iTunes) in the hope of restoring it. I've tried a few things, but while Things is still visible in iTunes, it hasn't shown up in my iPhone.

Is there any way that I can restore Things from iTunes to my iPhone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're absolutely sure that you have SYnced the phone and the app is still not there, you can try to remove it from iTunes too. Then you go to the App Store (make sure you are logged with the SAME account you were when you bought it for the first time) and buy it again, the store will inform you that it's "a free upgrade" and will re-download it. It will *not* charge you again.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure it is selected as an application that syncs to the iPhone.  If it is visible in iTunes then it should still be able to be synced.  If that doesn't work then open up the app store on the iphone and install it from there.  You won't be charged as you have already purchased it.

Answer (score -1):

If you have back up your content, you can restore from the backup.

To restore information from a backup, use one of the following methods after connecting your iOS device to the computer with which you normally sync:

1. Right-click (or Control-click) the device and choose Restore from Backup
2. If you have a new phone, you can connect to iTunes and it will prompt to restore from your backup
   Solution from Apple.com: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1766

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question about how to recover Things specifically.