# What is the process for restoring iPhone from a backup that is NOT in iTunes?

Tags: iphone, backup, restore

I would like to restore my iPhone from a backup that is not listed in iTunes. How can I do that? The backup file is saved on my computer hard drive. Thx.

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/77793/88313).  It tells you how to restore using iTunes and navigating to the backup on your hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

Is the backup folder in the right location on the hard drive? iTunes only lists backups in the MobileSync/Backup folder. If you need to move the folder there, here's instructions for Mac and Windows for getting to that folder: https://deciphertools.com/blog/where-are-iphone-backups/

If it's in the right place, let's make sure it's not a version issue. iTunes won't show backups as a restore choice if they are incompatible with the version of iOS you're restoring to.

1. Open the iTunes Preferences (iTunes menu on Mac, and Edit menu on Windows)
2. Change to the "Devices" tab.

If you see the backup listed in Devices, iTunes recognizes the backup, and the issue is that the device you're restoring to is running a lower version of iOS than the device that made the backup.

Comment: Thx for the response. It was not a version issue. It was a matter of finding the backup on my drive...the long story is that I backed up the phone on new MacBook Pro...and reset to factory settings. Backup was encrypted...and I had no idea what password was!!! I moved the backup to my iMac where the password was in my keychain...but then I finally figured out the password after many attempts, so I was able to restore from the MacBook. Thx for your answer!

Comment: @Sizzle If you were able to resolve your problem, please post that as an answer and accept it.  That will help others in the future who might have a similar problem.  See [answer].

Comment: Thx for your help with this...in all seriousness, should I post "I finally remembered my password" as my answer? I don't think that will be much help to someone else. Please advise. Thx.